# I lost the ability to view breakpoints values inside my Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2012. and i used to view run time values for all the breakpoints. but currently i can not retrieve this window again. can anyone advice which window i should chose to view ?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. Are you looking for the definition of the breakpoints themselves? That would be Debug / Windows / Breakpoints. If you want to view the value of variables after you've hit a breakpoint, that's Debug / Windows / Watch and the other various variable windows.

Comment: The window i use to have will show the run time values, so all the values defined insdie my code, such as object, XML m variables. but i can not re-view it again !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the menus along the top;

Debug->Windows->Breakpoints, Will list the locations of your breakpoints.

Debug->Windows->Watch->Watch [1-4], Will list any variables you have marked to watch.

Debug->Windows->Autos, Will list active variables.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the window i used to have , will show al the run time values , XML revived, current values for local variables , etc.

Comment: Updated my post, Debug->Windows->Autos